# How to get currently running EventLoop in python36?

Tags: python-3.6, python-asyncio

I know that in python37 we have a new api `asyncio.get_running_loop()`, which is easy to use, let us do not need to pass eventloop explicitly when we call a coroutine.

I'm wondering if there's any approach we can use to get the same effect in python36?

```py
# which allows us coding conveniently with this api:
import asyncio

async def test():
    print("hello world !")

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    loop.create_task(test())

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: @user4815162342 Indeed , big thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python 3.6 you can use `asyncio.get_event_loop()` for equivalent effect.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-eventloops.html#asyncio.get_event_loop), it is equivalent to calling `get_event_loop_policy().get_event_loop()`, which is in turn [documented](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-eventloops.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoopPolicy.get_event_loop) to return "the currently running event loop" when called from a coroutine.

In other words, when invoked from a coroutine (or from a function invoked by a coroutine), there is no difference between `get_event_loop` and `get_running_loop`, both will return the running loop. It is only when no loop is running that `get_event_loop()` will keep returning the loop associated with the current thread, while `get_running_loop()` will raise an exception. As long as you are careful to call `get_event_loop()` while a loop is actually running, it will be equivalent to `get_running_loop()`.

Note that `get_event_loop` returning the running loop when called from a coroutine is [new to Python 3.6 and 3.5.3](https://github.com/python/asyncio/pull/452). Prior to those versions, `get_event_loop` would always return the event loop associated with the current thread, which could be a different loop from the one that is actually running. This made `get_event_loop()` fundamentally unreliable and is the reason why old asyncio code would pass the `loop` argument everywhere. More details [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/python-tulip/yF9C-rFpiKk/tk5oA3GLHAAJ).